# Why does every permutation in an $l$-fold transitive group alter at least $2l-2$ symbols?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

I recently came across [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/2EFA97CA2861D1A3C2E24BE5900D284A/S0008414X00030911a.pdf/the-mathieu-groups.pdf) article by R.G. Stanton in which he states:

> Since every permutation other than the identity of an l-fold transitive group must alter at least 2l-2 symbols...

Why is that true?
I attemped an induction over $l$:

For $l=1$, every permutation $\sigma\neq id$ obviously alters more than $2\cdot 1-2 = 0$ symbols.

Assume the result is proven for $l-1$. Let $G$ be an $l$-fold transitive group. Since $G$ is also $l-1$-fold transitive, every non-trivial permutation must alter at least $2(l-1)-2 = 2l-4$ symbols. But why can't a permutation alter $2l-3$ symbols?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $S_3$ is (obviously) 3-transitive on $\{1,2,3\}$ but no element moves at least $2\times 3-2=4$ symbols.

Comment: You are right. Maybe he looks at $l$-fold transitive groups on $12$ symbols? (Because this chapter is about $M_{12}$?

Comment: I'll ask another question how this is meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question: This statement is obviously wrong as @user10354138 stated.

Take $S_3$ as a $3-$transitive group on ${1,2,3}$. No permutation moves at least $4$ symbols.