# Why does any non-trivial permutation of ${\rm Aut}(S(5,6,12))$ at least alter $8$ symbols?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, automorphism-group, combinatorial-designs

In my study on Mathieu Groups I came across the following [article](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/2EFA97CA2861D1A3C2E24BE5900D284A/S0008414X00030911a.pdf/the-mathieu-groups.pdf).
R.G. Stanton states on the second page:

> ... thus $M_{12}$ is $5$-fold transitive and so has order $m_{12} = 12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 9\cdot 8 \cdot k$, where $k$ is the order of the subgroup leaving five persons invariant. Since every permutation other than the identity of an $l$-fold transitive group must alter at least $2l-2$ symbols, it is necessary that $k$ be unity and so $m_{12} = 95040$.

As discussed in my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245257/why-does-every-permutation-in-an-l-fold-transitive-group-alter-at-least-2l-2), the $2l-2$ argument doesn't hold for every group (take $S_3$ as a $3$-transitive group).

But this result is only needed for a group on $12$ symbols (which is maybe what R.G. Stanton meant).

So the question arises whether any permutation of a $5$-fold transitive group on $12$ symbols moves at least $8$ symbols. This would make his argument correct.

EDIT: As discussed in the comments, $M_{12}$ is defined in terms of the automorphism group of a Steiner System $S(5,6,12)$. The "$2l-2$"- argument then only needs to apply to this group.

Comment: Staunton is pretty terse at that point. My guess is that this fact only applies when it deals about an $\ell$-transitive symmetry group of an $S(\ell,n,m)$ Steiner system. This pretty much rules out the symmetric and the alternating groups. But, I don't see it right away.

Comment: Yes, this could be possible. Should I rephrase my question?

Comment: It's obviously not true in general, as $(1,2)$ in $S_{12}$ shows. Yes, it's because it's a Steiner system. Since he uses it to deduce that the group is *sharply* $5$-transitive, it clearly wouldn't be true for any $5$-transitive groups that are not sharply $5$-transitive.

Comment: Can you give a hint on why it is true for a Steiner system? @DavidA.Craven ?

Comment: Since it isn't true for $M_{24}$ either, it is because of the *particular* Steiner system. In other words, Stanton is just dead wrong in his proof. You have to work with that system, and then you can see it.

Comment: Stanton is right about the non-identity elements of $M_{12}$ having at most four fixed points (and hence moving at least $8$), but the non-identity elements of $M_{24}$ move at least $16$ points. [WP on $M_{12}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_group_M12#Conjugacy_classes), and [$M_{24}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_group_M24#Conjugacy_classes). So it's not like the limit reads *at least $2\ell-2$ points must be moved in a non-identity symmetry of an $\ell$-transitive group of symmetries of $S(\ell,n,m)$*.

Comment: Okay, thank you all for your effort! :)

Comment: There may still be an "easy" lower bound that if a Steiner system $S(\ell,n,m)$ has an $\ell$-transitive symmetry group, then any non-identity symmetry moves at least $2\ell-2$ points. This would be consistent with the evidence here, and with what Stanton said.  I just don't see where such a bound would come from, but I didn't think about it too much :-(